# Jquery NavBar ,contents on same page

Tags: jquery, navbar

I have  a navigationbar that is made in bootstrap.When I click the link I should get the link contents in the same page in a div or just down the navigationbar using Jquery or Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

look into [anchor links](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm), you could use them to create a simple one page site with 'links' in your navigation header linking to #partone #parttwo and simple put these section headers in your page as

Answer (score 0):

> Using object tag

**HTML**

```
<div id="exUrl">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#exUrl").html('<object data="http://www.w3schools.com" style="width:100%;height:100%"/>');
});
```

**jsfiddle**
[Load external url](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/bqn2ax3t/)

> Using Ajax

[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

> Update

[Ajax load page when click on anchor](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/fxxo9L9j/2/)

Comment: I have  a php page .Navigationbar contains links to pages.I want links to pages on the same page by showing the contents in the div when I click the links,the contents should be displayed in the div corresponding to different links